# HH IC100 amplifier

Tags: schematics

Can anyone please decipher how the connections on the schematic of this amplifier for the **Sustain foot-switch** and also the schematic for the **Tri-vibrato/Reverb foot switch** are actually connected with the normal 1/4 TRS plugs used. I have been baffled by this drawing since they do not show any sleeve connections on them nor distinguish between T,R or S and the conductor lines with the circles mean nothing to me also.
If any one, with an understanding of this archaic schematic representation reads this, I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Welcome! _”this archaic schematic representation”_ Please do show!

Comment: You can use CTRL+v to paste an image into the post.